# How to group contents in a list from item to item based on whether those items are in another list?

Tags: python, list, grouping

I have the following list:

```
x = ['0001', 'Random message XYX', 'Random second message IAI', '0002', 'Random message IAM', 'Random second message OMA', 'Random third message OMA', '0003', 'Random message XAK', 'Random second message YAB', '0004', ' Random message INA']
```

I also have another list

```
y = ['0001', '0002', '0003', '0004']
```

I want to group list **x** based on group **y** so that the output is:

```
x = [['0001', 'Random message XYX', 'Random second message IAI'], ['0002', 'Random message IAM', 'Random second message OMA', 'Random third message OMA'], ['0003', 'Random message XAK', 'Random second message YAB'], ['0004', ' Random message INA']]
```

I have tried:

```
x = ['0001', 'Random message XYX', 'Random second message IAI', '0002', 'Random message IAM', 'Random second message OMA', 'Random third message OMA', '0003', 'Random message XAK', 'Random second message YAB', '0004', ' Random message INA']

y = ['0001', '0002','0003', '0004']

grouped_list = []
for entry in x:
    if entry in y:
        new_list = []
        new_list.append(entry)
        for i in range(x.index(entry)+1, len(x)):
            if(x[i][0] not in y):
                new_list.append(x[i])
            else:
                break
        grouped_list.append(list(new_list))
print (grouped_list)
```

However this just prints **[]**

Can someone please show me what I need to do to print the output I am after?

## Edit:

I have made some changes using y.luis' answer which worked for this example, however I have discovered an issue when using my actual data. I have duplicate entries in both lists, which is causing it to overwrite the data in the **x** list, not just group it. If this code is run, the last part of the **x** list is overwritten:

```
x = ['0001', 'Random message XYX', 'Random second message IAI', '0002', 'Random message IAM', 'Random second message OMA', 'Random third message OMA', '0003', 'Random message XAK', 'Random second message YAB', '0004', ' Random message INA', '0001', 'Random message ryryry', 'Random second message ryyryyryryry']

y = ['0001', '0002','0003', '0004', '0001', '0002']

grouped_list = []
for entry in x:
    if entry in y:
        new_list = []
        new_list.append(entry)
        for i in range(x.index(entry)+1, len(x)):
            if(x[i] not in y):
                new_list.append(x[i])
            else:
                break
        grouped_list.append(list(new_list))
print (grouped_list)
```

Can someone show me how to avoid this?

Comment: For starters, you have called both your iterables `entry`. Perhaps name them `entry_x` and `entry_y`

Comment: Your `y` list is not the same on your code blocks. In fact, the last block result is empty since none member of `y` is on `x`

Comment: Your `y` list contents do not appear in `x`, and also your conditional for breaking out of the inner loop is incorrect - it's not evaluating entries in `x`, just their first character

Comment: Yes that was a typo with the y list, I have fixed it. And you are correct, I was evaluating the first entry [0]

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your most inner `if`:

```
if(x[i][0] not in y):
```

here you are checking whether the first character of the item is on the list. It should be:

```
if(x[i] not in y):
```

If you you want to avoid group keys duplicated, you can use a dictionary:

```
grouped_list = []
d = {}
i = 0
current_key = None

while i < len(x):

    if x[i] in y:
        current_key = x[i]
        if not d.has_key(current_key):
            d[current_key] = []
        i += 1
        continue

    while i < len(x) and x[i] not in y:
        d[current_key].append(x[i])
        i += 1

for k in d:
    grouped_list.append([k] + d[k])

print (grouped_list)
```

Comment: Sorry, although that example works, I am having one problem with my actual code. I have duplicate entries in my y list. I have edited my question to show the issue

Comment: I updated to a dictionary based solution where you can avoid duplicate keys. If you want to also avoid duplicates in "non keys", you can check if `d[entry]` does not contains it before appending.

Comment: I have tried your updated solution but it is still not printing the last few entries in the **x** list i.e. '0001', 'Random message ryryry', 'Random second message ryyryyryryry'

Comment: I am getting the error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Answer (score 1):

How about a two liner? (Sorry, couldn't do it in one line)

```
# At the top of your .py file    
from __future__ import print_function

x = ['0001', 'Random message XYX', 'Random second message IAI', '0002', 'Random message IAM', 'Random second message OMA', 'Random third message OMA', '0003', 'Random message XAK', 'Random second message YAB', '0004', ' Random message INA']
y = ['0001', '0002', '0003', '0004']

indexes = [k for k in [x.index(toks) for toks in y]]
print([x[i:j] for i, j in zip(indexes, indexes[1:]+[len(x)])])
```

Gives me

```
[['0001', 'Random message XYX', 'Random second message IAI'],
 ['0002',
  'Random message IAM',
  'Random second message OMA',
  'Random third message OMA'],
 ['0003', 'Random message XAK', 'Random second message YAB'],
 ['0004', ' Random message INA']]
```

Comment: Are you able to show full working code? I can't get that working for some reason

Comment: @david_10001: Well, I have edited my answer a bit. But there is pretty much nothing else. The above snippet as such works for me.

Comment: @david_10001 It uses python2 print so it won't work on python3.  Try it online here: https://tio.run/##dY8xD4IwEIV3fsVtQCQG0InEoW7EoIkTpOlApEpBWkIZwD@PlIBBheku9917965s61Rwt@saOADWbdt2dAv0a8wTUUBBpYwfFMIonE0lvQmefKCPfAV7qbsg9VGwLr0EaAbrlFV/rLfdLSVCp3XbCB1H6V5V@I10RjrR2q@Hp/TTuUFLNI3xhDZUqt0c7qKCHBgH3GwHYNQil@YwV51CLSFaWTFe90uYeRkZKLMgU/TFSmO0tGBssOORDX5SbjQmMUnXvQE

Comment: You need to change `print` to `print()` :D [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY8/D4IwEMX3forbwEgMihOJQ92IQRMnSNOBSJWKtoQyFL880gYM/kuHu9yv7927qm0KKYKu07AB4vi@v3Q8cI6ZyOUd7kyp7MIgSZPJVLGTFPkLRjgysJeufkgjHP@XHmI8gU3B6y/W2wa/EuHdf9sUbwfp2lT4jLTHDkXt28Fj@nGd1VKEuMiZZsr8LeEsayiBCyB6YYHbyFLN7Nx0BrWUoqrmogGXaMLDK7WYe3A1@MErd/D0YGjIMqRzcmPC1TPav657Ag "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: I am getting invalid syntax on the **for** in the print line

Comment: @david_10001: That is because Python 3 has a different `print` function syntax. The edited answer is Python 2/3 compatible. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBa8IwFMfv@RTv1srKqLqT4CG7FdHBTkoIRWw6n12TkkRI/fJdEupwU5NDHu/H75@XdL09KjkfhlqrFsqyPtuzFmUJ2HZKW@g0Suu78mBRSeJgCSzJ83yaZJB87mXlrVYYs/8SsN1tb7pGHJSsfmFBiwC9OnugFnT9XP1Y0xtoj6jvmI@dP5qIrp7H7uj7qL6FE/6PtKEJJ/2fB1@nv14XXU5gXARlJZwwwWmgVhoaQAnMvUaQWtWYSeyHKqCecxK/GFLmGC5OPGLM4BTwBbt0zMxgLNh0wV/Yt5Cpm3C/h@EH "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Okay, I have that example working now, thank you. However my actual code is still buggy. It is only grouping some of them up to a point. I have no idea why.

Comment: Also, if I have two strings that are the same in group **y** it will output that group twice. The only thing I can change in the **x** list is the addition of [ and ]